# Unable to login with correct password

Tags: authentication

About a week ago, **all** users of WordPress site started receiving the login error "*Error: The password you entered for the username XXXX is incorrect*".

I changed to a default theme and disabled all plugins to rule those out. I also enabled debug, but the log didn't show anything relevant.

Working with my user login, I am reproducing the issue with the following WP CLI commands:

```
wp user update [id] --user-password=[password]
sh: 1: /usr/sbin/sendmail: not found
Success: Updated user [id].
wp user check-password [id] [passsword]
echo $?
0
```

In this code block, I used square brackets to represent actual values I'm putting in.

Email is not working on this site, but it has been that way for some time, and, as I understand, it should not cause login failure.

I have researched and requested support from the hosting company but haven't found a solution.

If it were just my login, I would look towards a specific problem with my user, but (as noted above) this problem affects all users.

Just in case it could be relevant, this is a multi-site instance.

Can anyone provide any pointers as to why an invalid password could be reported when the password is definitely correct?

Comment: corrupted or locked db table? Try editing other data from that table. Db logs? Reinstall core files?